# Search for a null value using Ransack 'eq' predicate

Tags: ruby, ransack

Using the 'eq' predicate with a blank value, Ransack will cancel out that predicate. Which is obviously handy to have an "All" option in your select.

But what if I want to **add an option in my `<select>` for null values too**? In order words how to produce the SQL query `SELECT * FROM spree_orders WHERE order_cycle_id = NULL` using the 'eq' predicate.

My test code (with results) is below. What I would like is to filter out the `Order`s where `order_cycle_id == nil`

```
Spree::Order.search(order_cycle_id_eq: nil).result.map(&:order_cycle_id)
Spree::Order Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "spree_orders".* FROM "spree_orders" 
 => [nil, 1, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 1, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 4, nil, 4, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

The second option is what I'd like to add to my select. I've tried 'null', 'nil', `nil`, etc..

```
<select id="q_order_cycle_id_eq" name="q[order_cycle_id_eq]">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="nil">No Order Cycle</option>
  <option value="1">Order Cycle 1</option>
  <option value="2">Order Cycle 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you asking what to put instead of `nil` in `Spree::Order.search(order_cycle_id_eq: nil)` or are you asking what to put instead of `???` in `<option value="???">`? They don't necessarily have to be the same. Sure, it would be nice, but you can always have `<option value="none">` and then have `if params[order_cycle_id_eq] == 'none'` and pass something else. I don't know what `Ransack` is though.

Comment: Both: the option value would be passed through to the value in `.search(order_cycle_id_eq: value)`. I've updated my question to consistently use `nil` as the example.

Answer (score 8):

Try this in console:

```
Spree::Order.search(order_cycle_id_null: true)
```

In html view set  and then in your controller change ransack query

Comment: That's how I ended up doing a work around: something like "if params[:order_cycle_id] == 'null' then order_cycle_id_null: true"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I came across a similar issue and found [in the docs](https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/using-predicates/#null) that you can actually do an `IS NULL` query, which helped in my case.

```
User.ransack(first_name_null: 1).result.to_sql

>> SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."first_name" IS NULL
```