# Submit nil as value for f.check_box when checked with ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I think I am just using the rails [check_box](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box) form helper incorrectly.  Here is the relevant part of the form.  I am using [ransack](https://rubygems.org/gems/ransack) but I don't think it makes a difference here:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <%= f.label :date_closed_eq, "Only Open Cases" %><br>
  <%= f.check_box(:date_closed_eq, {}, nil, false) %>
</div>
```

When the check box is checked and the form is submitted here is the parameters hash:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"date_closed_eq"=>"on"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
```

So for some reason "on" is passed through.  But I want it to be `nil`.  Not sure what I am missing here.

I did notice [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730792/search-for-a-null-value-using-ransack-eq-predicate) but that question never had an answer, and my attempts to apply it were not successful.

[Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447777/rails-gem-ransack-search-or-condition-with-is-null-and-a-specific-value) but again no accepted answer and I am still having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong predicate:

```
  <%= f.check_box(:date_closed_null, {}, true, false) %>
```